# Only make drop down choice clickable if another drop down is checked

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a combo box called status with open and complete. I also have another combo box called approvals with options pending approved or rejected.

My goal is to make the option complete in status only available if someone chooses approved in the approval combo box first. I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Use Conditional Formatting to enable/disable combobox based on value of other combobox. Use VBA to Null second combobox if first combobox value is changed. Any chance 'approved' could be changed to 'rejected'? Screwups do happen.

Comment: But if 'approved' also means 'complete' and rejected can never be 'complete', why bother with Status field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a form to mimic your form as described and cam up with the following:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Status_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.Status = "Complete" Then
         If Nz(Me.Approvals, "") <> "Approved" Then
        Me.Status = "Open"
    End If
End If

End Sub
Private Sub Approvals_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.Approvals <> "Approved" Then
        If Me.Status = "Complete" Then
            Me.Status = "Open"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This solution forces the value back to Open when anything does not match your logic.  You may want to throw in a message box to so the user understands why the change is forced.